# Flash cs4 local security sandbox

Tags: javascript, flash, security

I'm testing a flash script that calls a JavaScript function (both, the swf and the HTML file are local). The flash movie is not allowed to access the HTML file that contains the js-function.

I've learned that I have to put both files into a security sandbox, so I added the path to both files (HTML+swf) to a file test.cfg in C:\WINDOWS\system32\Macromed\Flash\FlashPlayerTrust.

But still the same problem. What to do?

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The requirement for calling from Flash to JS is that you have the allowScriptAccess parmeter set in your embedding code of your HTML document. Iirc, you can specify always or sameDomain and it will work. The second option obviously require the swf to be coming from the same domain.